# Improving an ARIMA model by eliminating AR/ME terms

Tags: time-series, arima, autoregressive, moving-average, differences

I've come over the following two statements to manually improve the fit of an ARIMA model by changing its parameters $p,q$.

> If the AR coefficients sum to nearly 1 and suggest a unit root in the
> AR part of the model, **eliminate 1 AR term** and difference the model once (more).

> If the MA coefficients sum to nearly 1 and suggest a unit
> root in the MA part of the model, **eliminate 1 MA term** and reduce the
> order of differencing by 1.

(From: Stefan Jansen, Hands-On Machine Learning for Algorithmic Trading, 2018)
Quote relate (might originate) from Rule 9: [https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim3.htm](https://people.duke.edu/%7Ernau/411arim3.htm)

I am wondering does the "eliminate 1 _ term" refer to decreasing or increasing the respective hyperparameter?
I assume that it means decreasing, but what would be the theoretical justification/practical changes be behind these adjustments to create a more suited model?

Comment: Can you give a source for that quote?

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, now also found an online source - maybe I find the answer there.